# What LDAP query to get 0 results?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

In Alfresco there is a field where I can specify which groups to sync, with an LDAP query.

I don't want to sync groups, so what query can I type, to always return 0 result?

I guess I could just write a query searching for a crazy condition, but is there something more readable?

Comment: Can you just use a X == NOT X type condition?

Comment: @PreetSangha: Good idea, a bit like `SELECT a = 1 WHERE 1 = 0` in SQL. Could you please propose it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just use a X == NOT X type condition?

As long as the condition is prominent then everyone should be able to understand.